# why chatMsgStore.addChatMsg(bdmsg) does not effect the store?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

store.js

```
import {useLocalObservable} from "mobx-react-lite";

function chatStore() {
    return {
        chatmsg: [],
        setChatMsg(arr) {
            this.chatmsg = arr
        },
        addChatMsg(msg) {
            this.chatmsg.push(msg)
        }
    }
}

export const useChatStore = () => useLocalObservable(chatStore)
```

app.js

```
    const App = () => {

    const chatMsgStore = useChatStore()

    const AppFunctions = {chatMsgStore}

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on(activechat.chatid, (bdmsg) => {
            chatMsgStore.addChatMsg(bdmsg)
        })
        return () => {
            socket.off(activechat.chatid)
        }
    }, [activechat, chatMsgStore.chatmsg])

    return (
        <>
           <AppContext.Provider value={AppFunctions}>
                 .....................
           </AppContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
  }

  export default App;
```

fetch.js

```
async function getChatMessages(url, body, userStore, chatMsgStore) {
........
            chatMsgStore.setChatMsg(firstResData)
........
```

on app load i add a socket listener which deps are **activechat** and **chatMsgStore**.
this listener is dynamic and must be changed when deps change.
the only purpose of this listener is to add a msg to the store and re-render the observer component

deps :
activechat - non store state
chatMsgStore.chatmsg - store state

why chatMsgStore.addChatMsg(bdmsg) does not effect the store? so deeply nested components inside App.js is not re-rendering.

otherwise i have a function **getChatMessages** which i import from custom hook deep inside App.js which sets the messages. this func is not a child of App.js and it is not wrapped with **observer**    **chatMsgStore.setChatMsg(firstResData)** works! i can set the message so the observer component will re-render
how to make this code in useeffect above work?

Comment: observer is not needed here.
reaction is not needed here.
because i dont render anything in App.js component, i just using addChatMsg(bdmsg)  method which adds data into the store.  
i dont know what was the problem but now the code above works great.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `autorun` from `mobx` in order to set correctly the reactivity in `useEffect`, [here](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#useeffect) is a link to the doc that explains why and how use it.

But I think that you should not put `chatMsgStore.chatmsg` inside the deps array because you're not using it inside the `useEffect`.

If you can provide a working example maybe we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` component is not wrapped with `observer` HOC so it won't react to `observable` values changes.

Wrap it like that:

```
const App = observer(() => {
  // ...
})
```

or when exporting:

```
export default observer(App)
```

[More info in the docs](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html)